# Select change with data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Ly1973u/.

Here's my html:

```
<article>
  <select>
    <option name='First' value='first'>First</option>
    <option name='Second' value='second'>Second</option>
    <option name='Third' value='third'>Third</option>
  </select>
  <div data-name='first' class='show'>
    This one should show by default.
  </div>
  <div data-name='second'>
    only visible when "second" is selected
  </div>
  <div data-name='third'>
    only visible when "second" is selected
  </div>
</article>
```

Basically, I want to have the first div show by default, but when you change the select to second or third, I want it to change to that div.

I realize I could do this easy with an if statement, but I could potentially have a lot of select options, so I'm hoping for a cleaner solution. Or is this the only way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function () {
    $("select").on("change", function () {
        $('.show').removeClass('show');
        $('div[data-name="' + $(this).val() + '"]').addClass('show');
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4Ly1973u/1/

Comment: if I wanted to have multiple of these, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/3kwoLw54/, it changes both?

Comment: @Muhambi yes. If you don't want change both divs, you can use this code http://jsfiddle.net/3kwoLw54/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Ly1973u/3/

```
<article>
    <select>
        <option name='First' value='first'>First</option>
        <option name='Second' value='second'>Second</option>
        <option name='Third' value='third'>Third</option>
    </select>
    <div id='first' class='show'>This one should show by default.</div>
    <div id='second' class='noshow'>only visible when "second" is selected</div>
    <div id='third' class='noshow'>only visible when "third" is selected</div>
</article>
```

CSS

```
.show {
    display: block;
}
.noshow {
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $("select").change(function () {
        $('.show').removeClass('show').addClass('noshow');
        var getValue = $("select option:selected").val();        
            $("#" + getValue).removeClass('noshow').addClass('show');
    });
});
```